# Custom Field Alerts in TFS 2012

Tags: tfs-alerts

I added a custom field (Product Owner) in `TFS`. Since I wanted a drop down of valid `TFS` users, I copied the setup of the Assigned To control `(String, Dimension, ALLOWEXISTINGVALUE, VALIDUSER)`. I want to be able to set up an alert that says:

```
Product Owner = [Me]
```

but equals is not an available option in the operator drop down list. When I try to set up an alert my only options for this field are `Changes, Changes From, Changes To`.

Suggestions?
Thanks,
Troy

Answer (score 3, accepted):

•    In the Eventing system, there are two types of fields: core fields and non-core fields. When building the alert definition, you can only use Changes, Changes From and Changes To for certain core fields. In the Alerts Explorer Alert Definition, there are different operators depending on whether the field is a core field or not.  Core fields will have =, <> and other equality operators along with Changes, Changes From and Changes To.  All other fields only have the change-based operators.
Core fields that are part of every work item type are listed below:
-          Activated By
-          Activated Date
-          Area Path
-          Assigned To
-          Attached File Count
-          Authorized As
-          Changed By
-          Changed Date
-          Created By
-          Created Date
-          Description
-          ID
-          Iteration Path
-          PortfolioProject
-          Reason
-          State
-          Title
-          Work Item Type
All other fields are in the non-core field category.
When there is a change in the system, the Eventing system creates an XML message to represent that change.  To reduce data volume and processing overhead, the XML message contains the values for the core fields and the values for any field that changed.  It does not contain any non-core fields that did not change.

Sorry, this seems not possible here.

Maybe some others have some dirty tricks, I would love to know : )

Thank you!

Evgeniya

Answer (score 0):

Has anyone found a work around for this? I don't see why I can't use the variable "[Me]" for a custom field, cmon Microsoft. I'd guess maybe use a hidden field that does a check for this or something along those lines

Comment: found a MSDN thread : [Not getting the "=" in Alerts explorer](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b6f2ed98-6f66-4b86-bc95-1d7123cac1ba/not-getting-the-in-alerts-explorer?forum=tfspowertools)